# Convert list of IDs into other values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a string being returned from a query that returns a list of ids to another table. The string can contain 1 id or a list of ids separated by commas.

I would like to convert the list of ids such that refer to another field (in this case a name) from the ids primary table.

E.g. `select * from task` returns:

```
taskid,jobid,start,finish

1,"333",09:00,12:00

2,"334",08:00,16:00

3,"333,334",09:00,17:00
```

and I would like to reference the '`job`' table such that '`job.name`' is returned in place of `job.jobid` within the string. So it would look like this:

```
taskid,jobid,start,finish

1,"Wash",09:00,12:00

2,"Dry",08:00,16:00

3,"Wash,Dry",09:00,17:00
```

Comment: You need an [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial/sql_inner_join.cfm).

Comment: But how can I get the string to remain as comma separated values just showing name rather than id?

Comment: I did not notice that it was a single string.

Comment: If you are wanting a pure SQL solution this will be difficult as it doesn't handle comma-lists very well. Usually this would be done with a join table, creating a one-to-many join between Task and Job records.

Answer (score 0):

You've run into one of the many problems of storing denormalized and specifically, *delimited* data.  The standard solution, relationally speaking, is to create a junction table to represent this many-to-many relationship between `task` and `job` (e.g. "JobToTask").

However, if you can't change your current situation, one way to do this is to loop through your set and make replacements one iteration at a time:

```
-- Create a temporary spot for id replacements
declare @output table (
    taskid int, jobnamelist varchar(1000)
)
insert into @output select taskid, ',' + jobid + ',' from task

-- Run replacements
while exists (select null from @output t join job j on t.jobnamelist like '%,' + cast(j.jobid as varchar(50)) + ',%') begin
    update t
    set jobnamelist = replace(
                            jobnamelist,
                            ',' + (select cast(min(jobid) as varchar(11)) from job where t.jobnamelist like '%,' + cast(jobid as varchar(50)) + ',%') + ',',
                            ',' + (select name from job where jobid = (select min(jobid) from job where t.jobnamelist like '%,' + cast(jobid as varchar(50)) + ',%')) + ','
                        )
    from @output t
    where exists (select null from job where t.jobnamelist like '%,' + cast(jobid as varchar(50)) + ',%')
end

-- Get final output
select taskid, substring(jobnamelist, 2, len(jobnamelist) - 2) as jobnamelist
from @output

--   taskid jobnamelist
--   ------ -----------
--        1 Wash
--        2 Dry
--        3 Wash,Dry
```

Take special note of adding the delimiters to both ends of a string ALWAYS when finding or making the replacement.  This prevents you from replacing part of an ID (e.g. 33 is in 334).

If you have to do this in a single select statement you might use a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to run similar logic.

One corner case to think of is if you have a `job.name` that exists in your `job.id` column...you would end up replacing something twice (or more) and would thus have to build in a check for that (a replacement history field or temp table, potentially).